# Unable to connect to Ubuntu server via VNC due to previous inappropriate disconnect

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc

Normally I can connect to a ubuntu server via vnc viewer. But sometimes due to inappropriate disconnect of the session because of the internet change, or just unplug the internet cable, then the current session becomes died and prevents me from connecting to the server again within a half-hour. But SSH is still usable. Could anyone teach me to know to handle this issue? I heard from someone that I need to kill the session via ssh, but I don't know exactly what to do. 
Thank you very much for help.